# OpenCart 3.0 - Authorize.net PHP module - how to add Line Items & Custom Fields?

Tags: opencart, authorize.net, opencart-3

Website built on OpenCart 3.0.2.0, using the standard (included with OC) payment module for Authorize.net.

Problem #1: need to add Line Items (individual item information) to the transaction.

Problem #2: the Authorize.net AIM PDF reference shows only hardcoded examples, no idea how to turn them into dynamically-generated array.

Problem #3: don't know nearly enough PHP to figure it out on my own.

Here's the current code of authorizenet_aim.php... if anyone can show me how to add line items to this mess, I would really, really appreciate it!

```
    <?php
class ControllerExtensionPaymentAuthorizeNetAim extends Controller {
public function index() {
$this->load->language('extension/payment/authorizenet_aim');
$data['months'] = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
$data['months'][] = array(
'text'  => strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2000)),
'value' => sprintf('%02d', $i)
);
}
$today = getdate();
$data['year_expire'] = array();
for ($i = $today['year']; $i < $today['year'] + 11; $i++) {
$data['year_expire'][] = array(
'text'  => strftime('%Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $i)),
'value' => strftime('%Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $i))
);
}
return $this->load->view('extension/payment/authorizenet_aim', $data);
}
public function send() {
if ($this->config->get('payment_authorizenet_aim_server') == 'live') {
$url = 'https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll';
} elseif ($this->config->get('payment_authorizenet_aim_server') == 'test') {
$url = 'https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll';
}
//$url = 'https://secure.networkmerchants.com/gateway/transact.dll';
$this->load->model('checkout/order');
$order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
$data = array();
$data['x_login'] = $this->config->get('payment_authorizenet_aim_login');
$data['x_tran_key'] = $this->config->get('payment_authorizenet_aim_key');
$data['x_version'] = '3.1';
$data['x_delim_data'] = 'true';
$data['x_delim_char'] = '|';
$data['x_encap_char'] = '"';
$data['x_relay_response'] = 'false';
$data['x_first_name'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_firstname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_last_name'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_lastname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_company'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_company'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_address'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_address_1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_city'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_city'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_state'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_zone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_zip'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_postcode'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_country'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_country'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_phone'] = $order_info['telephone'];
$data['x_customer_ip'] = $this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$data['x_email'] = $order_info['email'];
$data['x_description'] = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_name'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_amount'] = $this->currency->format($order_info['total'], $order_info['currency_code'], 1.00000, false);
$data['x_currency_code'] = $this->session->data['currency'];
$data['x_method'] = 'CC';
$data['x_type'] = ($this->config->get('payment_authorizenet_aim_method') == 'capture') ? 'AUTH_CAPTURE' : 'AUTH_ONLY';
$data['x_card_num'] = str_replace(' ', '', $this->request->post['cc_number']);
$data['x_exp_date'] = $this->request->post['cc_expire_date_month'] . $this->request->post['cc_expire_date_year'];
$data['x_card_code'] = $this->request->post['cc_cvv2'];
$data['x_invoice_num'] = $this->session->data['order_id'];
$data['x_solution_id'] = 'A1000015';
/* Customer Shipping Address Fields */
if ($order_info['shipping_method']) {
$data['x_ship_to_first_name'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_firstname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_last_name'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_lastname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_company'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_company'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_address'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_address_1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' ' . html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_address_2'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_city'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_city'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_state'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_zone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_zip'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_postcode'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_country'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['shipping_country'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
} else {
$data['x_ship_to_first_name'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_firstname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_last_name'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_lastname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_company'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_company'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_address'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_address_1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' ' . html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_address_2'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_city'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_city'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_state'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_zone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_zip'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_postcode'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data['x_ship_to_country'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_country'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
if ($this->config->get('payment_authorizenet_aim_mode') == 'test') {
$data['x_test_request'] = 'true';
}
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$json = array();
if (curl_error($curl)) {
$json['error'] = 'CURL ERROR: ' . curl_errno($curl) . '::' . curl_error($curl);
$this->log->write('AUTHNET AIM CURL ERROR: ' . curl_errno($curl) . '::' . curl_error($curl));
} elseif ($response) {
$i = 1;
$response_info = array();
$results = explode('|', $response);
foreach ($results as $result) {
$response_info[$i] = trim($result, '"');
$i++;
}
if ($response_info[1] == '1') {
$message = '';
if (isset($response_info['5'])) {
$message .= 'Authorization Code: ' . $response_info['5'] . "\n";
}
if (isset($response_info['6'])) {
$message .= 'AVS Response: ' . $response_info['6'] . "\n";
}
if (isset($response_info['7'])) {
$message .= 'Transaction ID: ' . $response_info['7'] . "\n";
}
if (isset($response_info['39'])) {
$message .= 'Card Code Response: ' . $response_info['39'] . "\n";
}
if (isset($response_info['40'])) {
$message .= 'Cardholder Authentication Verification Response: ' . $response_info['40'] . "\n";
}
if (!$this->config->get('payment_authorizenet_aim_hash') || (strtoupper($response_info[38]) == strtoupper(md5($this->config->get('payment_authorizenet_aim_hash') . $this->config->get('payment_authorizenet_aim_login') . $response_info[7] . $this->currency->format($order_info['total'], $order_info['currency_code'], 1.00000, false))))) {
$this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory($this->session->data['order_id'], $this->config->get('payment_authorizenet_aim_order_status_id'), $message, false);
} else {
$this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory($this->session->data['order_id'], $this->config->get('config_order_status_id'));
}
$json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/success', '', true);
} else {
$json['error'] = $response_info[4];
}
} else {
$json['error'] = 'Empty Gateway Response';
$this->log->write('AUTHNET AIM CURL ERROR: Empty Gateway Response');
}
curl_close($curl);
$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
}
```

Comment: How many line items do you have?

Comment: What you've posted is more like a mini-project than a technical question in my view, if you don't know PHP you should probably just pay a developer to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

**Path:** *public_html/catalog/controller/extension/payment/authorizenet_aim.php*

**Line items:**

```
$products = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrderProducts($this->session->data['order_id']);

$post_string = "";
foreach( $data as $key => $value )
    { $post_string .= "$key=" . urlencode( $value ) . "&"; }
$post_string = rtrim( $post_string, "& " );


$line_items = array();
$index  = 1;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $line_items[] = 'item' . $index . '<|>' . $product['name'] . '<|>' . $product['model'] . '<|>' . (int) $product['quantity'] . '<|>' . (int) $product['price'] . '<|>Y';
    $index++;
}

foreach( $line_items as $value )
    { $post_string .= "&x_line_item=" . urlencode( $value ); }
```

**Custom Fields:**

```
/* Merchant Defined Fields */
$data['Order'] = $data['x_invoice_num'];
$data['Item_1'] = "";
$data['Model'] = $data['x_description'];
$data['Qty'] = "";
$data['Price'] = $data['x_amount'];
$data['Taxable?'] = "";
```